# PHP Mysql to upload a pipe delimeted file

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 set of files file_csv.csv , file_pipe.txt, file_tab.txt from the function

```
function file_download_table($table,$qry='') {    

if(!empty($qry)) {
    $query  = $qry;
} else {    
    $query  = "SELECT * from $table";
}

if(isset($_GET['fn'])) {
    $nameoffunction = $_GET['fn'];
    $nameoffunction($table,$query);
}
```

}

```
to_CSV() { 
  //Code for CSV Download 
}

to_PIpe() { 
  //Code for Download as PIPE
}
```

so for the reversing process(upload after changes with the downloaded file) is it possible ?

Comment: Ignoring the actual question for a second, this code is dangerous due to a user being able to run any PHP function they like.

Comment: Yes, it is - what have you tried? As a side note, calling a function based on unvalidated user input is a huge security hole

Comment: consider now i have a file_csv.csv , it contains the records updated and i want a custom page where i can upload the file  eg) function file_upload($file,$table) { }

Comment: first of all the function is for my personal use with my local db